# Infinite Ajax Scroll jQuery - Update title on scroll / pageChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll, jquery-ias

Is there any possibility to get the TITLE in the head to get updated when scrolling?

Im using Infinite Ajax Scroll.
http://infiniteajaxscroll.com

```
var ias = jQuery.ias({
container:  '#posts',
item:       '.post',
pagination: '#pagination',
next:       '.next'
});

jQuery.ias().on('pageChange', function(pageNum, scrollOffset, url) {
    // Update Page Title
});
```

Comment: The library provides events. Listen to the appropriate event, and in the callback, update the title.

Comment: I have tried on the pageChange-function to update document.title but haven't got it to work.

Comment: Well please post that function in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue with Infinite Ajax Scroll.
The only solution I found was to extract the title from "data" on the "loaded" event.

```
ias.on('loaded', function(data, items) {
        var title = data.match(/<title[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/title>/)[1];
        document.title = title.replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
            .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
            .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
            .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
            .replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
    })
```